# DESIGN PROBLEM: How to use composition the best

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I'm working on a project and have some doubts about it's design.
How can I design the following problem the best (in JAVA):

**Class A** with the following attributes:

- HashSet of Pixels where each pixel has x,y coordinates and value v between 0-1.
- instance of class B.

**Class B** with the following function:

- a function that gets a Pixel and returns its left neighbor.

When I'm in class A I want to use B.function on each pixel in A and add it to the HashSet only if it's not already there. The problem is that I don't want to send the HashSet to the function, how bad is it to return new instance of Pixel from the function if it might already exist (This function going to run on many pixels and will create many unused instances of Pixel).

What other options do I have?

Comment: If you have a `HashSet<Pixel>`, the only way to see if a pixel is in the set, is to create another pixel, so unless you change this aspect, you don't really have any other options for the function in class B, since it would have to create the `Pixel` object even if you did pass in the HashSet.

Comment: Thanks, so I wonder how bad is it on performance if in every call to B.function, the function creates 10 instances I wouldn't use? Is it acceptable to do something like that?

Comment: You don't think a two-dimensional array of double is a better representation of this?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt In my case, given an image I might need to hold only some pixels within it so I think holding a two-dimensional array representing all the image might be wasteful.

Comment: How many pixels out of an image of which size? There's a definite overhead associated with creating objects for each pixel, storing X and y, and the allocations for a HashSet. And if your pixels are in a rectangular area you would only need a matrix for that area. And if you still need a Hash lookup, a HashMap with a Point (x and y) object as key and Double as value is a more natural representation

Comment: @AviadBenShabat Is there a way you can reuse the same `Pixel` instance rather than creating a new one for each call to `function` in `B`? Create a new instance only when the `add` method returns true, indicating that the `Pixel` was not present and has been added to the `Set`?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt - I can't know in advance, it can be a very large image and the set of pixels I want to store are neighbors but can be in any area in the image with unknown size. Is there a difference between using HashMap (that stores x,y as key and double as value) vs using Hashset that stores Pixel (that contains x,y,value)?

Comment: @CKing - in order to use the "add" function to a HashSet of Pixels, don't I need to send Pixel object to "add" ? If yes it means I will need to create the instance any way before using add

Comment: Since you use `Set<Pixel>` you need to create a `Pixel` instance to check if it exists in set or not. The same is for `add` method. So, you have to do that and in this scenario there is no other option. If set already contains `N` elements after running a method you will create extra `N` elements of left neighbours for each element in set. Now, if all elements are new, you just store them. In other case `GC` needs to sweep them.

Comment: @AviadBenShabat, have you solved this problem? Which solution did you choose?

Answer (score 0):

Since you use `Set<Pixel>` you **have to create new** `Pixel` instance to check if it exists in set or not.

If set contains `N` elements after calling `B.function` method you will create extra `N` `Pixel` nodes. If all elements are new, you just add them to set, in other case `Garbage Collection` needs to sweep them. One of drawbacks is we need to create `m` (wheren `m <= N` - number of `Pixel`-s which already exists in set) and later we need to collect them by `GC`. How big is `m/N` ratio depends from your algorithm and what you are actually doing.

Lets calculate how many memory we need to consume for `N = 1_000_000` pixels in set. We know that `int` is a `4 bytes` and `double` is `8 bytes`, lets add extra `8 bytes` for an object and `8 bytes` for a reference. It gives `32 bytes` for every instance of `Pixel` object. We need to create `N` objects which gives `32MB`. Let's assume that our ratio is `50%` so, `16MB` we allocated just to check it is not needed.

If this is a cost you can not pay you need to develop algorithm which allows you iterate over `Set<Pixel>` in an order from `left-to-right`. So, left neighbour of `Pixel` `X` is before `X`.

Assume that left neighbour of `Pixel` `X(x, y)` is pixel `X'(x - 1, y)`. `Pixel` `B(0, y)` does not have left neighbour. You need to use `TreeSet` and implement `Comparable<Pixel>` interface in `Pixel` class. Simple implementation could look like this:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Pixel o) {
    return this.y == o.y ? this.x - o.x : this.y - o.y;
}
```

This allows you to iterate set in order from left to right: `(0, 0), (1, 0), ...., (x - 1, y), (x, y), (x + 1, y), ... , (maxX, maxY)`. So, when you iterate it you can check whether previous element is a left neighbour of current `Pixel`. Example implementation could look like below:

```
void addNeighboursIfNeeded() {
    Set<Pixel> neighbours = new HashSet<>(pixels.size());
    Pixel last = null;
    for (Pixel p : pixels) {
        if (p.getX() == 0 || p.isLeftNeighbour(last)) {
            // a left border pixel
            // or last checked element is a left neighbour of current pixel.
            last = p;
            continue;
        }
        // last element was not our left-neighbour so we need to call b method
        Pixel left = b.getLeft(p);
        neighbours.add(left);
        last = p;
    }
    // add all new neigbours
    pixels.addAll(neighbours);
}
```

This should allow you to save this memory which is allocated for duplicated `Pixel` objects.

Answer (score 0):

I can see here few concerns regarding object oriented programming.

1. Encapsulation violation: When you call function of B from A which operates on A's data (which you are avoiding by not sending HashMap), it violates encapsulation (If there is a reason, its acceptable though). Is it possible to move that function (operating on A's HashSet) to A? This will protect A's state from getting exposed.
2. Proliferation of classes: There is a possibility that there will be large number of objects of Point type. You can think of using Flyweight GOF design pattern, it will externalize the state of each point and will make it reusable. and will reduce number substantially.
3. Passing large collection of Points to method in B: If you can shift method from B to A, this point gets resolved. Anyway java will pass this collection by reference. But in that case its open for modifications from external classes (need to take care of this aspect).
4. Abstraction of type *Point*: If class Point has only state and no behavior, it will lead to violation of encapsulation. Can you shift the method *getNeighbour()* in to Point? as it will make Point immutable (which is essential). Off course actual algorithm can be delegated to another class (if its independently varying responsibility and has hierarchy of algorithms, think of GOF Strategy pattern here).
5. Uniqueness of points in collection: which your set will take care with due care about appropriate Hash and logical equality for class Point.